Package 'ros_gz_sim' not found: "package 'ros_gz_sim' not found, searching:
Good afternoon, Is there anyone who know how to solve this issue, when I try to launch a file with ros2 it says that the package is not found.
error in terminal
I've installed the package cloning the ros_gz_sim repository and it stills doesn't find the package.
picture of the existing file
I'm on MacOS btw.
